# Get Location form GPS and set marker on google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am trying to getting location(latitude and longitude) from Gps and set marker on google map  but it is not working.In this code I am trying to get latitude and longitude from gps  Location Listener method onLocationChanged but this method never calling not showing any toast.

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {
    private static View view;
    private SupportMapFragment mMap;
    private static Double latitude = 28.6538100, longitude = 77.2289700;
    GoogleMap gMap;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private MinDisLocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationManager lm;

    public MapsFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        locationListener = new MinDisLocationListener();
        lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 2, this.locationListener);
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 2, this.locationListener);
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
            mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gMap = map;
        gMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
//        drawMarker(latitude, longitude);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
                LatLng(49.39, -124.83), 20));
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco")
                .snippet("Population: 776733"));
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 2, this.locationListener);
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mMap = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMap).commit();
            mMap.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


    private void requestPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    public void drawMarker(double lat, double lon) {
        if (gMap != null) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(" Maps Tutorial").snippet("Android Ruler");
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            gMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000, 2, this.locationListener);
                    }
                    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 2, this.locationListener);
                } else {


                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mMap = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mMap).commit();
            mMap.getMapAsync(this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
    }

    public class MinDisLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("location", "onLocationChanged");
            drawMarker(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLocationChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("location", "onStatusChanged");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onStatusChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("location", "onProviderEnabled");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onProviderEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("location", "onProviderEnabled");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onProviderEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Msnifist File Is this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.deltastar.catchme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    - See more at:
    http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample#sthash.PtrAvZrk.dpuf
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/register" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OtpVerifyActivity"
            android:label="@string/otp_verify" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChatMemberActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateGroup" />
        <activity android:name=".AddMemberGroup" />
        <activity android:name=".MeatPointName" />
        <activity android:name=".MyMeeting" />
        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GroupInfo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapChat"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_chat" />
        <activity android:name=".MyMeatingReq" />
        <activity android:name=".UserProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".MyProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".Settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DrawerDemo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drawer_demo"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MeetingPointLocation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_meating_point" />
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".MyLocation" />

        <activity android:name="com.services.LocDemo" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fragment.MapsFragment">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please show manifest file

Comment: Can u post fragment_map and your activity xml?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfect. You just have to move your device in the place where gps is available, because the place where you are testing your app may not have exposure to GPS satellite.
onLocationChanged() will be called once GPS is detected by the device

Comment: are You sure that my code is working perfect and what solution that if GPS satellite not found on that place

Comment: Yes i comment the statement "drawMarker(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());" and tested code, it displayed Toast "onLocationChanged"

Comment: Ok thanks nikhil but i test it other place toast showing only once location not update after 5000 sec or 2 meters

Answer (score 0):

Check your project from there
 http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial 
But i think problem with manifest 
Have you this

```
<permission         android:name="tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"         android:protectionLevel="signature" />     <uses-feature         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"         android:required="true" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />     <uses-permission android:name="tj.tajdev.mrking.whatisonindushanbe.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this

```
<meta-data             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```